# Does fortify two-handed increase damage done with bows?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

It's unclear to me whether "two-handed" means just two-handed melee weapons, or if it includes bows.

Logically, a bow is used with two hands, so it should work, but I want to make sure before I waste a black soul gem on a 13% fortify two-handed magic ring.

**So, does "Two-handed attacks do 13% more damage" apply to bows, or just melee weapons?**

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No.

Bows are not considered 'Two-handed weapons' in this sense because they're based on the **Archery** skill, not the **Two-Handed** skill.

If it makes it easier, think of the skill as being named *Two-Handed Melee* and abbreviated.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. I was thinking of Two-Handed as a weapon property instead of the skill.

Comment: I thought the same thing, that a bow is a "two-handed" weapon. But all the enchantments, equipment and potions I tried out, did not make any difference for me. I was doing just fine with poisons applied, so I took off all one handed and two handed perks in the skill tree and put them into Archery and Alchemy.

Answer (score -8):

Yes. Bows are included in the two-handed skill tree even though it has a skill tree of its own.

It's because the bow requires two hands to wield, and the game mechanic is a tribute to real life, since it's impossible to fire a bow and arrow with one hand.

In Skyrim, you also can't fire a bow and arrow with one hand. But, by using a bow, you only gain half the XP for the two-handed skill tree that you would gain from a hammer or great sword

Comment: Punctuation is your friend!  Also, do you have a source for this?  It sounds flat-out wrong.

Comment: @Matthew [This thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615804-/61722990) disagrees with you.

Comment: My personal experience totally disagrees with this. i have 100 in archery and like 20 ish in two-handed (more or less where it started). So, no xp gain on my end.

Comment: Down vote. This is just plain wrong.