# Skyrim : does "Two-handed attacks do 13% more damage" apply to dual casting spells, or just melee weapons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

It is unclear to me if "Two-handed attacks do 13% more damage" apply to dual casting spells, or just melee weapons?
because basically dual cast is a two-handed attack.
please help

Comment: If you check your "active effects", it's listed as Fortify 2-handed skill.

Answer (score 2):

It applies only to attacks with two-handed melee weapons.

If it helps, reread the language as *attacks based on your 'two-handed weapon' skill do 13% more damage.*

[And before you ask, yes, that means it doesn't apply to bows either.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35858/does-fortify-two-handed-increase-damage-done-with-bows)

Answer (score 2):

No. Two-Handed attack bonuses only apply to attacks with a two-handed melee weapon.

Answer (score 1):

No.  That bonus doesn't apply to bows or duel casting spells.  It pertains to the Two-handed weapon skill weapons only.